# Integrating Apache Guacamole with Physical Webcam and Microphone in Remote Desktop Setup

Tags: guacamole

I am working on a project where I need to utilize a physical computer's webcam and microphone in a remote desktop environment using Apache Guacamole. I've set up Apache Guacamole successfully for remote desktop access, but now I want to enable webcam and microphone functionality

1. How can I configure Apache Guacamole to recognize and utilize the local webcam and microphone?
2. Are there specific configurations or plugins that need to be added to enable webcam and microphone support?
3. Any additional steps or considerations for ensuring proper functionality of the webcam and microphone within the remote desktop session